# docker swarm container bind address other than 0.0.0.0

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-networking

I got a multi-node docker swarm setup with the following interfaces:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:8d:c0:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.2.15/24 brd 10.0.2.255 scope global dynamic eth0
       valid_lft 47333sec preferred_lft 47333sec
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fe8d:c04d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eth1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 08:00:27:fe:3f:4d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.2/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fefe:3f4d/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:94:ee:64:8f brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.1.2/24 brd 10.0.1.255 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
9: docker_gwbridge: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default 
    link/ether 02:42:12:4b:f2:fa brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.18.0.1/16 brd 172.18.255.255 scope global docker_gwbridge
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::42:12ff:fe4b:f2fa/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

When starting the most simple container stack `docker swarm deploy -c simple.yml simple`

```
version: "3.7"
services:
  whoami:
    image: traefik/whoami
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

The container get placed and the service gets bound to `0.0.0.0`. Not exactly ideal.
Better would be for the container to bind to the `eth1=10.0.1.2/24` interface. Ideally also `lo` - but that would be just the icing on the cake.

What I've tried is to start the docker instances with their respective IPs from the network.

> --ip ip   Default IP when binding container ports (default 0.0.0.0)

So based on [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/) for example: `dockerd --ip 10.0.1.2`. Unfortunately that does not seem to change a thing.

I am using `Docker version 20.10.4, build d3cb89e`.

Any advise what I might be missing?

Answer (score 2):

Currently it's not possible to bind a swarm service to a specific IP. See this more than four year old issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/26696

You can init your swarm with the `--advertise-addr` `--data-path-addr` and `--listen-addr` option bound to your `eth1` interface to limit some of the internal swarm traffic to this interface, but this will not really solve the problem.